# How can I add extra text to a Venn diagram in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a Venn diagram that has additional text to what is generated by data and category information. Specifically, I want to add text to the center of a 5-way Venn and also on the outside of the Venn. I created the diagram using the following code using the package VennDiagram:

```
venn.plot <- draw.quintuple.venn(
area1 = 301, area2 = 321, area3 = 311, area4 = 321, area5 = 301,
n12 = 188, n13 = 191, n14 = 184, n15 = 177,
n23 = 194, n24 = 197, n25 = 190,
n34 = 190, n35 = 173, n45 = 186,
n123 = 112, n124 = 108, n125 = 108,
n134 = 111, n135 = 104, n145 = 104,
n234 = 111, n235 = 107, n245 = 110,
n345 = 100,
n1234 = 61, n1235 = 60, n1245 = 59,
n1345 = 58, n2345 = 57,
n12345 = 31,
category = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
fill = c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod1", "darkorange1", "seagreen3",  "orchid3"),
cat.col = c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black"),
cat.cex = 1.5,
cat.dist = c(-0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.005),
margin = 0.2,
cex = 0,
ind = TRUE);

grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

This works great, but I would want to add some text in the center of the diagram and also in the white space between categories 1 and 2. I would also want to add some sort of symbol (an "x" for example) on the outer border of each ellipse of the diagram.

I would so much appreciate any help!